# How to save into multiples related tables in jhipster (Spring)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

Sorry I'm new to jhipster, I have three related tables through

```
>      Student 1=>* StudentCourse *<=1 Course
```

I am wondering how I can save to the 3 tables an object StudentCourse that I have constructed and populated. This Object is connected to the object student and course through setters:

```
studentCourse.setStudent(...) & studentCourse.setCourse(...)
```

I want to save the object into the database I have tried to persist using JPA:

```
studentCourseRepository.save(studentCourse)
```

The studentCourse is created, the student, and the course related. is this the approach ? Should I save each object alone first ? (save Student, then Course, then studentcourse ? ) I heard about transactional, should I use that approach ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Is 'studentCourse' persisted alone?

Comment: {
    "message": "error.internalServerError",
    "description": "Internal server error",
    "fieldErrors": null
}
Normally what should happen if I save into studentCourseRepository ?

Comment: can you edit your question to include your JPA annotaions?

Comment: Normally, when u save the object in discussion. This update the entity studentCourse. In your gateway, in entity menu, you can manage this, and save one record for u studentCourse, but only if you create the relation correctly. U used jdl for entity and relationships?

Comment: In fact, I have a correct relationship, now when I save the studentCourse, it automatically adds the student and course related.

Comment: So, this update your entity correctly. This is your problem?